# R parsing tsv, subscript out of bounds error

Tags: r, csv

I am very new to R and am running into an error with reading in a file.

```
importSilvaNgsDataFile <- function(file){
  sampleNames <- unlist(strsplit(readLines(file,n=1),split="\t"))
  otuTable <- read.csv(file, header=FALSE, sep="\t",quote="",dec=".", skip=1,row.names=length(sampleNames)+1)
  inputData <- list(sampleNames=sampleNames, otuTable=otuTable)
  return(inputData)
}

mydata <- importSilvaNgsDataFile('silva_otus.tsv')
```

this gives the error:

```
Error in data[[rlabp]]: subscript out of bounds
```

`silva_otus.tsv` looks like:

```
    31_F6_57.8  32_F7_55.4  36_F1_57.1  37_F2_57.2  41_E6_55.1  42_E7_56.6  43_E8_57.3  44_E9_58.3  46_D1_55    47_D2_56.7  48_D3_57.2  49_D4_58    51_D6_53.6  52_D7_55    53_D8_56.7  56_E1_52.4  57_E2_55.2  58_E3_56.6
ID0000002M  408 355 293 805 256 292 614 345 505 455 353 53  231 203 417 581 249 342
ID0000003M  120 207 43  142 71  60  266 825 89  87  194 1807    91  68  261 151 33  69
ID0000007M  13  16  12  37  9   9   25  62  7   13  15  120 9   6   38  16  10  12
```

I am unable to see how `rlabp` comes up, I never try in index into anything with `[rlabp]`. I tried searching for `rlabp` and didn't see any obvious connections. Is there something wrong with the function?

Comment: Looks like it's an issue with the number of rows you're expecting, are you sure that that number of row.names from the strsplit operation is what you're after?

Comment: your row.names is a single digit "20", But it is supposed to be a vector of length equal to row numbers. even if you say `1:length(sampleNames)+1` that will be 20 item vector when you have just 3 rows. Please review what you are trying to achieve with `row.names`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is here (I'm not an R programmer, so not really sure) :

```
sampleNames <- unlist(strsplit(readLines(file,n=1),split="\t"))
```

This will give a list with an empty field up front (there is a `tab` before the first value)

```
row.names=length(sampleNames)+1
```

Here you add 1 to the length of that list, probably thinking there's one item less in the header, which is not the case.

The tsv data itself is valid.

**Update**:

Ok, did a quick test in R, the above seems to be the problem.

To solve the `subscript out of bounds` remove the `+1`:

```
row.names=length(sampleNames)
```

But this uses the values of the last column as the row names..:

```
$sampleNames
 [1] ""           "31_F6_57.8" "32_F7_55.4" "36_F1_57.1" "37_F2_57.2" "41_E6_55.1"
 [7] "42_E7_56.6" "43_E8_57.3" "44_E9_58.3" "46_D1_55"   "47_D2_56.7" "48_D3_57.2"
[13] "49_D4_58"   "51_D6_53.6" "52_D7_55"   "53_D8_56.7" "56_E1_52.4" "57_E2_55.2"
[19] "58_E3_56.6"

$otuTable
            V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 V11 V12  V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18
342 ID0000002M 408 355 293 805 256 292 614 345 505 455 353   53 231 203 417 581 249
69  ID0000003M 120 207  43 142  71  60 266 825  89  87 194 1807  91  68 261 151  33
12  ID0000007M  13  16  12  37   9   9  25  62   7  13  15  120   9   6  38  16  10
```

You probably want to use the first column for the names (`row.names=1`):

```
otuTable <- read.csv(file, header=FALSE, sep="\t",quote="",dec=".", skip=1, row.names=1)

$sampleNames
 [1] ""           "31_F6_57.8" "32_F7_55.4" "36_F1_57.1" "37_F2_57.2" "41_E6_55.1"
 [7] "42_E7_56.6" "43_E8_57.3" "44_E9_58.3" "46_D1_55"   "47_D2_56.7" "48_D3_57.2"
[13] "49_D4_58"   "51_D6_53.6" "52_D7_55"   "53_D8_56.7" "56_E1_52.4" "57_E2_55.2"
[19] "58_E3_56.6"

$otuTable
            V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 V11 V12  V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19
ID0000002M 408 355 293 805 256 292 614 345 505 455 353   53 231 203 417 581 249 342
ID0000003M 120 207  43 142  71  60 266 825  89  87 194 1807  91  68 261 151  33  69
ID0000007M  13  16  12  37   9   9  25  62   7  13  15  120   9   6  38  16  10  12
```

Comment: I appreciate the thorough response, that was the problem. Thanks.